# Change body styles with viewEncapsulation Emulated in angular 4

Tags: css, angular, webpack, sass, angular-cli

In my angular 4 app, inorder to make the shadow dom selectors work, the viewEncapsulation was changed from none to emulated. But, this breaks the styles applied to body tag. It works only if viewEncapsulation is set to none. Is there any way to make both shadow selectors and body styles work?